# Excel file export nothing happens with no error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel, web

I have trying to export my data from my data access layer 
but nothing happens no error and not exported.
it is kinda hard to know whats wrong because there's no error

I have tried this:

```
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0){
          dgv.DataSource = dt;
         dgv.DataBind();

         Response.ClearContent();
         Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachement;filename=transaction.xls");
         Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
         StringWriter stringWritter = new StringWriter();
         HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWritter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWritter);

        dgv.RenderControl(htmlTextWritter);
        Response.Write(stringWritter.ToString());

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

butnothing happens.

i have tried this but also nothing:

```
         StringWriter osStringWritter = new StringWriter();
         Html32TextWriter osHtmlTextWritter = new Html32TextWriter(osStringWritter);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();            

         Response.Clear();
         Response.Buffer = false;
         Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", "TransactionReport"));
         Response.Charset = "";

         dgv.DataSource = dt;
         dgv.DataBind();

         dgv.RenderControl(osHtmlTextWritter);
         Response.Write("Report Datw:" + DateTime.Now);
         Response.Write(osStringWritter.ToString());
         //Response.End();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
         HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        dgv = null;
        osStringWritter = null;
        osHtmlTextWritter = null;
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please format your code.. yes you will need to remove most of the spaces

Comment: done formatting anyone could help me?

Comment: my stringWritter have the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this may resolve your issue

```
dgv.DataSource = dt;
        dgv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = Export to Excel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                dgv.RenderControl(htw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Response.End gives me error Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Comment: still same, nothing happens